# How to accept HTTP 400 and HTTP 500 as valid response codes in Visual Studio Load Test?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, load-testing

I am using the Visual Studio 2013 web testing framework to stress-test a REST service. I want to measure how well the application performs when presented with pathological/malformed JSON in POST request. The server is responding with either HTTP 400 or HTTP 500 and I would like to consider both a success response.

I tried validating the response with the pass-all event handler:

```
public class MalformedBodyTest : WebTest 
{
    private void Validate(object sender, ValidationEventArgs e)
    {
        e.IsValid = true;
    }

    public MalformedBodyTest()
    {
        this.ValidateResponse += Validate;
    }

    ...

}
```

This does not seem to have any difference, the responses are still showing up as failed.  Using `ExpectedHttpStatusCode` property of `WebTestRequest` works fine but only enables me to test for a single HTTP status code.

I would like the request to be considered failed just if the timeout is reached. Is there any way to achieve this functionality?

Comment: Smells like a bad and very confusing idea...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, that was actually quite simple. I missed that there is also a property `IgnoreHttpStatusCode` in `WebTestRequest`. By setting it to `true` in the request generator

```
public override IEnumerator<WebTestRequest> GetRequestEnumerator()
{
    for (var i = 0; i < Iterations; ++i)
    {
        var request = new WebTestRequest(_url);
        request.IgnoreHttpStatusCode = true;

        ...

        yield return request;
    }
}
```

I was then able to precisely set which HTTP status codes to accept and which to reject in the validation handler:

```
private void Validate(object sender, ValidationEventArgs e)
{
    e.IsValid = (e.Response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.BadRequest ||
                 e.Response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError);
}
```